# Show output before and then prompt for input in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want the user to enter output after the question displays but PL/SQL prompts for input as soon as I run the program.

I use this code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( chr(10) || 'What is the capital of Srilanka?');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1.Colombo 2.Candy 3.Galle 4.Dhaka'|| chr(10));
    Ans1 Number := &Ans1
END;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just want the printed statement to show before the user prompt for input

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate of the question "PL/SQL: how do i prompt user input in a procedure"

Comment: please any one who can resolve this

Comment: PL/SQL runs on the server and is not interactive. You will need to split the question and answer into separate sections in your script.

Comment: Thanks William, I'll try to do it